# Reflexivity of a relation between different sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

How are you doing? I have a question in Algebra:
how can we describe the reflexivity of a relation defined in a set that is  resultant of a cartesian product of two different sets **A**={a,b,c} and **B**={d,e,f}: where:
**A** x **B**={(a,d);(a,e);(a,f);(b,d);(b,e);.....} and considering the graph of the relation is:
**G**={(a,d);(b,d);(c,f)}
How can the reflexivity be expressed here in **G**?
should we say (could be wrong) for the first couple :

aRa and dRd

- however i know that in a **single** set (of elements x) where a relation R is defined we can express reflexivity by saying: xRx.

therfore I concluded that if we're dealing with **single** set elements of which are couples we could express it this way:

(a,d)R(a,d)

is that right?? Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand. I thought that, by definition, a relation on a set $X$ has to be a subset of the Cartesian product $X \times X$. You can come up with names for special subsets of an arbitrary Cartesian product $A \times B$, but I don't see how you'll ever define a reflexive property when $A \neq B$. Possibly if $A$ and $B$ are in bijection and you have a fixed bijection, but even then...

Comment: but see here in Wiki: "In mathematics, a binary relation on a set A is a collection of ordered pairs of elements of A. In other words, it is a subset of the Cartesian product A2 = A × A. More generally,** a binary relation between two sets A and B is a subset of A × B**

Comment: Yes, you're right. I had an *equivalence relation* in mind mistakenly, there are plenty of perfectly good relations between $A$ and $B$ when $A \neq B$. But my point still stands though that the reflexive property is specifically in place to say that "Each element is related to itself," and I don't know how you'll find a suitable notion when $A \neq B$.

Comment: i have another question please : how does my questions trike you are they aimless as my friends say?  they say that when I ask them they get confused

Comment: See [Reflexive relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_relation) for the definition.